# Is a big object also not well localised according to quantum mechanics?

Tags: quantum-mechanics

According to quantum mechanics particle is not localised at one position, our act of measurement make wave function to collapse at a position(Copenhagen Interpretation). A big object(like books on my table) is made of these small particle than do this object also not well localised when no one is observing it ? Please Explain?

Comment: See also: [Did I get hit by a car this morning?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/319706/did-i-get-hit-by-a-car-this-morning)

Answer (score 1):

What is the probability of one particle being found in a particular place, when you integrate the probability density between two finite limits?

Now with your book, you need to get the product of all these probabilities to check the likelihood that the book is no longer where you put it.

Multiplied together, a large number of ratios, each less than unity, is going to be  a tiny number, representing the chance of finding the book any significant distance from its original observed position.

Comment: +1 Yes, the uncertainty is only tiny microscopic.